# Не могу вывести связанную модель

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars

Здравствуйте! Ситуация следующая:

Имеются 2 модели: заметка и пользователь. У заметки есть поле "автор", через которое эти модели связаны как М-1. Для получения данных используется mirage. В шаблоне данные о пользователе не появляются.

Модель заметок:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    subject: DS.attr(),
    message: DS.attr(),
    user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
    created_at: DS.attr(),
    updated_at: DS.attr(),
});
```

Модель пользователя:

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    username: DS.attr(),
    email: DS.attr(),
    notes: DS.hasMany('note'),
});
```

Код в mirage:

```
let notes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        type: 'note',
        attributes: {
            subject: 'Test 1',
            message: 'tttttttttttttttttttttttt',
            user_id: 1,
            'created-at': '2017-03-10 15:04:22',
            'updated-at': '2017-03-10 15:04:22',
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        type: 'note',
        attributes: {
            subject: 'Test 2',
            message: 'klakljadlfkjhasdflij',
            user_id: 1,
            'created-at': '2017-02-10 15:04:22',
            'updated-at': '2017-02-10 15:04:22',
        }
    }
];

let users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        type: 'user',
        attributes: {
            username: 'user',
            email: 'user@email.com',
        }
    }
];

this.get('/notes/:id', function (db, request) {
    let note = notes.find((note) => parseInt(request.params.id) === note.id);
    let result = {
        data: note
    };
    if (request.queryParams.include === 'user') {
        result.included = [users.find((user) => parseInt(note.attributes.user_id) === user.id)];
    }
    return result;
});
```

При этом из mirage модель точно возвращается и распознается (показывается в EmberInspector).

В шаблоне HandleBars пишу `{{model.user.username}}`. Пусто. При этом, если написать `{{log model.user}}`, то выводится пустая модель.

Есть подозрение, что это связано с тем, что модель note уже присутствует на клиенте: чуть раньше грузятся все модели note для вывода списка, причем грузятся без пользователей.

Comment: `result.included = [users.find((user) => parseInt(note.attributes.user_id) === user.id)];` что в этот момент в `users`?

Comment: Добавил в текст вопроса